# How to avoid loading packages multiple times?

Tags: packages, compiling

I have to compile several latex files with the same packages (quite a few of them). Is it possible to load only one time the packages and then compile the multiple file?

It would save me a lot of time.

Comment: see `mylatex` or `mylatexformat` packages which allow you to make a custom format

Comment: The documentation of `mylatexformat` is not so clear. I will have a look to `mylatex`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Feel free to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mylatex` or `mylatexformat`, both available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org).

About how to use these packages, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269048/8323).