# Difference between mylatexformat and ini option of pdflatex

Tags: format-files

I know that I can significantly speed up LaTeX compilation times by using a format file. However there seem to be multiple options to create a format file:

- Just using the `ini` option of [`pdflatex`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdflatex.1.html) (in the sense
  `pdflatex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex preamble.tex\dump"`
- Use [mylatexformat](https://ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat) to create the format file

How do both approaches compare? What are the differences and advantages/disadvantages of one over the other? Or is there a third approach you should prefer in 2023? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try both options yourself. Essentially they're "the same", with `mylatexformat` offers some additional convenience.

Tutorial on `-ini`:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15606/250119

Tutorial on `mylatexformat`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377033/250119
or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269052/250119

Note that the latter **also** uses `-ini`.

The additional convenience of the package is that, if you use `mylatexformat`, then you

- don't need to keep two separate TeX files `preamble` and `main`, they're both in the same file.
- don't need to modify the source code (apart from a single format line at the start of the file. You **can** add `\endofdump` to explicitly mark the end of the "precompiled" part if you want/if anything in the preamble is not precompilable, but it's not mandatory, by default the part before `\begin{document}` is precompiled)

For other methods to speed up compilation refer to [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/250119).